# Odd "Creating the instance for IConfiguration failed" Configuration Error

Tags: .net, vb.net, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I'm setting up a SimpleInjector container, and I have one class that has a hierarchy like:

```
TestConfiguration (class I'm working with)
     BaseConfiguration (abstract class)
        IConfiguration (interface used for registering)
```

There are a lot of IConfiguration objects listed and I'm using a dynamic process for registration ([TEF](https://bitbucket.org/bmains/tef)).  This process brings them in and registered the IConfiguration interface against multiple types (25 to be exact).  I'm using the `container.RegisterAll(type, types())` overload.  It worked just fine until I added the TestConfiguration class, which follows the same approach as the others, but it breaks with the following error:

> Additional information: The configuration is invalid. Creating the
>   instance for type IConfiguration failed. No registration for type
>   TestConfiguration could be found.

Why?  It's clearly there, and it clearly implements the interface, and it was first in the list of types registered.  This error doesn't make sense since it's there...  I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and VB.NET.

The stack is also here:

> at
>   SimpleInjector.Advanced.ContainerControlledCollection`1.VerifyCreatingProducer(Lazy`1
>   lazy)    at
>   SimpleInjector.Advanced.ContainerControlledCollection`1.VerifyCreatingProducers()
>   at
>   SimpleInjector.Container.VerifyInstanceProducersOfContainerControlledCollection(Expression
>   expression)    at
>   SimpleInjector.Container.VerifyIfAllExpressionsCanBeBuilt(InstanceProducer[]
>   producersToVerify)    at
>   SimpleInjector.Container.VerifyIfAllExpressionsCanBeBuilt()    at
>   SimpleInjector.Container.Verify()

Comment: If upgrading to 2.7.1 doesn't fix this, please post the relevant part of your configuration to reproduce this.

Answer (score 1):

You are either using Simple Injector version 2.6.0, 2.6.1 or 2.7.0. What you are experiencing is [a bug](https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/workitem/21000) in these releases. If you upgrade to Simple Injector [v2.7.1](https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/releases/view/610797) your life will be good and pleasant again.

Comment: That was a good thought.  Didn't quite do it for some reason though.  I deleted and re-added the file with a new class name, and that did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

@Steven's idea was great, but that didn't do it for me.  Deleting and recreating the file with a new class name seemed to do the trick, for no logical reason whatsoever :=)